# making a vending machine out of GTK

Tags: gtk

```
#include "UI.h"

GtkWidget* create_main_frame(gint wid, gint hgt) 
{
    GtkWidget* main_frame = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    /* window attributes */
    gtk_window_set_title( GTK_WINDOW(main_frame), "Welcome!!" );
    gtk_window_set_default_size( GTK_WINDOW(main_frame), wid, hgt );

    /* signals */
    g_signal_connect(main_frame, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    return main_frame;  
}

GtkWidget* create_scrolled_window(void)
{
    GtkWidget* scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);

    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy( GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrolled_window), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS );
    gtk_container_set_border_width( GTK_CONTAINER(scrolled_window), 10 );

    return scrolled_window;
}

GtkWidget* create_box(GtkOrientation orn, gint spc)
{
    GtkWidget* box = gtk_box_new(orn, spc);

    //gtk_container_set_border_width( GTK_CONTAINER(box), 5 );

    return box;
}

GtkWidget* create_layout(guint wid, guint hgt)
{
    GtkWidget* layout = gtk_layout_new(NULL, NULL);

    gtk_layout_set_size( GTK_LAYOUT(layout), wid, hgt );    

    return layout;
}

GtkWidget* create_grid(guint rsp, guint csp)
{
    GtkWidget* grid = gtk_grid_new();

    gtk_grid_set_row_spacing( GTK_GRID(grid), rsp );
    gtk_grid_set_column_spacing( GTK_GRID(grid), csp );

    return grid;
}
/*
GtkWidget* create_token_button(Token* tkn)
{
    char parsed_value[11];
    char* string = parse_to_string(tkn -> value, parsed_value); 
    GtkWidget* button = gtk_button_new_with_label(value);

    //gtk_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK, );

    return button;
}
*/

GtkWidget* create_commodity_button(Commodity* com)
{
    GtkWidget* button = gtk_button_new_with_label(com -> name);

    //gtk_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK, );

    return button;  
}


#include "UI.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    /* vending machine */
    VendingMachine* vending_machine; 

    /* frames */
    GtkWidget* main_frame;
    GtkWidget* scrolled_window;
    GtkWidget* commodity_box, * commodity_layout, * commodity_grid, * commodity_button;

    /* initialize */
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    make_new_vending_machine_memory(&vending_machine, sizeof(VendingMachine) ); 
    boot_vending_machine(vending_machine, 13, 13);

    /* setting main frame */
    main_frame = create_main_frame(1000, 750);

    /* setting commodty frames and button table */
    commodity_box = create_box(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 10);
    scrolled_window = create_scrolled_window();
    commodity_layout = create_layout(500, 700);
    commodity_grid = create_grid(10, 10);

    for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                commodity_button = create_commodity_button(&vending_machine -> commodity[i][j]);
            gtk_grid_attach( GTK_GRID(commodity_grid), commodity_button, i * 300, j * 300, 5, 7 );
        }

    /* start adding and packing */
    gtk_layout_put( GTK_LAYOUT(commodity_layout), commodity_grid, 10, 10 );
    gtk_container_add( GTK_CONTAINER(scrolled_window), commodity_layout );
    gtk_box_pack_start( GTK_BOX(commodity_box), scrolled_window, TRUE, TRUE, 10 );
    gtk_container_add( GTK_CONTAINER(main_frame), commodity_box );

    /* show all */
    gtk_widget_show_all(main_frame);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm done writing the basic functions that are needed in my small vending machine project.

Now, I'm trying to make an UI out of the functions with GTK+. And I'm very confused since

this is the first time I'm actually using GTK.

I want a grid of commodity buttons that should be displayed on the left side, but I got

pretty much stuck on this part. What I'm trying to do is, since I "malloc"ed the commodities

for the purpose of adding and remove comms, I want a scroll bar attached to the comm window.

what I did as you can see in the source code

1. I made a grid of comm buttons and added on a layout widget.
2. I added the layout on a scrollbar widget
3. I added that scrollbar on a box and packed it.
4. I added that box to the main window.

the result is well "not satisfing"

I'm struggling through the GNOME official APIs

can somebody help me with this??

Comment: please separate and name the files we need to compile your program

Comment: "result is not satisfying" is not a good enough problem description, especially not if you don't share a compilable source file. That said,  looking at the source, using GtkLayout seems a bit odd: are you sure you need it? The most typical solution is a ScrolledWindow + Viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see how to create your user interface, give [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) a try. You'll be able to quickly try and see how the widgets fit together.